# Differential equations. Shortcut way to solve this problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

***Disclaimer: I am not a student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus from a textbook. I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

> The weight in pounds of a certain bear cub $t$ after birth is given by
>   $w(t)$. If $w(2)=36, w(7)=84,$ and $\frac{dw}{dt}$ was proportional to
>   the cub's weight for the first $15$ months of his life, how much did
>   the cub weigh when he was $11$ months old?

---

A friend of mine emailed me his solution:

> No calculus involved. $\frac{dy}{dy} = k y$ That implies $y=\exp(kt+C)$ One $(t,y)$
>   pair gives $k$, another gives $C$. You don't have to know the
>   differentiation, just the result, hence, no Calculus.

Can someone decipher what he's saying?  What is $\exp()$?  Exponent?  $y$ equals an exponent?  Huh?  I had no idea what he meant, and asked for clarification.    His alternate solution was

> If Diff. Eq. is of the form $\frac{dy}{dt} = ky$, then write solution as $y=$
>   $\exp(...)$ That's it!

I don't understand how this problem can be solved in just 1 line.  It's clear that he's addressing this problem with a totally different approach than the traditional "Calculus/DiffEq" approach.

Below is is how I did it.   Although I arrive at the correct answer after 10 mins. and an entire page of paper, I'd like to understand the 1-liner shortcut method above, as it seems a big time saver.  Can anyone explain his approach written out legibly in a photo scan?

[image]

Comment: The next time you solve a similar problem you can start with equation $w=Ce^{kt}$ and substitute the given conditions.

Comment: What is the rationale behind starting directly with that equation?  I see no mention of continuous compounding or exponential growth/decay in the original problem.  What rule of thumb/shortcut am I unaware of?

Comment: Because the solution of $dw/dt=kw$ is $w=Ce^{kt}$ as you computed. If $k=1$, then $w=Ce^{t}$. And if $w(0)=1$, then $w=e^{t}$, the exponential function.

Comment: Wait, the solution of dw/dt=kw is $w=Ce^{kt}$?  How?  This is how I understand derivatives:  If the derivative of w is kw, then isn't the antiderivative/original function $y=\frac{k}{2}w^2$ ??

Comment: $$w=Ce^{kt}\Rightarrow \frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}Ce^{kt}=C\frac{d}{dt}
e^{kt}=Ce^{kt}k=kw.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to write this way: if $\dot w = k w,$ then $$  w = C e^{k t}.  $$ You do not really need to solve for $k,$ because
$$  w = C \left( e^k \right)^t. $$ So, if we define a positive real number $M = e^k,$ we get
$$  w = M^t.   $$

This one does not come out pretty. I guess you are taking an approximation.

Given $w(2)= 36, w(7) = 84,$ we have
$$ C M^2 = 36, \; \;  C M^7 = 84,  $$ and
$$  M^5 = \frac{84}{36} =  \frac{7}{3}, $$
so
$$ M =   \sqrt[5]\frac{7}{3} \approx 1.184664 , $$ meanwhile
$$ C = 36 / M^2 \approx 25.65144.  $$
$C$ is the weight at birth.

Oh, well. Weight at 11 is 
$$ C M^{11} = C M^7 \cdot M^4 = 84 \cdot M^4 \approx 84 \cdot 1.969615 \approx 165.44769  $$

Maybe this will help: because $7-2 = 5,$ we get nice rational number weights at $t=2,7,12,17,22,$ and so on. 
$$  C M^{12} = 84 \cdot M^5 = 84 \cdot \frac{7}{3} = 196, $$
$$  C M^{17} = 196 \cdot M^5 = 196 \cdot \frac{7}{3} = \frac{1372}{3} = 457 + \frac{1}{3}. $$

The one with the 196 gives a way to confirm the answer, 
$$  C M^{11} = \frac{C M^{12}}{M} = \frac{196}{M} \approx  \frac{196}{1.184664} \approx 165.44769   $$

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two cubs starting with weights $w_0$ and $w_1$. When for both of them ${dw\over dt}=c\, w(t)$  with the same proportionality constant $c$, then the weights of both of them  multiply by the same factor within a week. From the data we conclude that this factor is $\left({84\over36}\right)^{1/5}$. Therefore in the remaining four weeks the cub increases his weight to $\left({84\over36}\right)^{4/5}\cdot 84=165.448$ pounds.

Comment: Clever! Clever!